# spring-boot does not honour @EntityScan in multimodule gradle build using GORM

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-orm, spring-boot, grails-2.0

I have a multimodule gradle build, using spring-boot and standalone GORM.

The domain entities are located in a separate submodule, so that these domain objects and gorm can be used across several spring-boot (and non-spring-boot) applications.

Structure

```
build.gradle
- module1-with-springboot-jersey  (depending on module 3)
-- src/main/groovy/geit/api/Application.groovy

- module2-with-springboot-groovytemplate (depending on module 3)

- module3-standalone-gorm-with-entities
-- src/main/groovy/geit/domain/../Animal.groovy

- module4-apache-camel-app  (depending on module 3)
```

When running gradle bootRun in module1, the jersey app, it starts the application, however when trying to access a rest resource returning an Animal, it fails with a stacktrace:

```
2014-11-03 13:16:03.679 ERROR 44316 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/api].[jerseyServlet]     : Servlet.service() for servlet [jerseyServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [geit.domain.entity.experimental.reku.Animal] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [geit.domain.entity.experimental.reku.Animal] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at geit.domain.entity.experimental.reku.Animal.currentGormStaticApi(Animal.groovy)
    at geit.domain.entity.experimental.reku.Animal.$static_methodMissing(Animal.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1493)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1481)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at geit.api.experimental.reku.AnimalsResource.greet(AnimalsResource.groovy:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     un.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.servComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:280)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
      g.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

So I read up on the documentation, and find this
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration
**Hmm.. @EntityScan looks promising**

So I annotate my Application class, like this

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=Animal)
class ApiApplication {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run ApiApplication, args
    }

}
```

But now, the gradle bootRun fails at startup

```
2014-11-03 13:20:43.790  INFO 44376 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2014-11-03 13:20:43.797 ERROR 44376 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan, ensure an appropriate bean is registered.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(EntityScanRegistrar.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(EntityScanRegistrar.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:692)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:962)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:951)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
      g.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at geit.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.groovy:31)

2014-11-03 13:20:43.798  INFO 44376 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4c85ba73: startup date [Mon Nov 03 13:20:35 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-11-03 13:20:43.801  INFO 44376 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2014-11-03 13:20:43.806  INFO 44376 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter      : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2014-11-03 13:20:43.806  INFO 44376 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter      : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2014-11-03 13:20:43.807  INFO 44376 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from @EntityScan, ensure an appropriate bean is registered.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(EntityScanRegistrar.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScanRegistrar$EntityScanBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(EntityScanRegistrar.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:692)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:962)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:951)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at geit.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.groovy:31)
:api:bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I've also tried with 
@EntityScan(basePackages = "geit.domain") to trigger scanning from a package higher in the hierarchy, but this gives the same error

But, if I move the domain/entity classes into the (jersey) application module, then it works. This however, prevents me from using gorm in more than one application. 
Which is something we need to achieve, so that module 1,2 and 4 above can use the standalone gorm module

**Is this a missing feature or bug?**
:)

PS. 
When moving the Application class to the top-level package, then it works ok! 
That is, from package **/geit/api/Application.groovy** to **/geit/Application.groovy**
All submodules have the same toplevel package name, so maybe that is why it works? 
It still puzzles my though

Comment: `@EntityScan` is for JPA and you aren't using it if you are using GORM (at least not in the form it was intended). I don't suppose there is an equivalent annotation. Maybe Graeme or one if the grails team can help more (if you can't add the grails tag ask and I'll do it for you).

Comment: Thanks. I've added the grails tag to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question left unanswered. Our solution is to convert from GORM to spring-data/jpa.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sort of hack way to do this.

Even if we're doing standalone GORM + Spring boot, GORM still gets an instance of a `GrailsApplication`.

So hook a bean post processor to the application. When it's turn to process `sessionFactory`, fetch the underlying `grailsApplication` and register your Groovy domain classes as domain class artifacts.

Here

```
@Component
class GrailsApplicationPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

   public static final String DEFAULT_SESSION_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME = "sessionFactory"

   public static final Class [] domainClasses = [
         Client.class, Feature.class, User.class
   ]

   @Override
   Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      if (DEFAULT_SESSION_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME.compareTo(beanName) == 0) {
         if (bean instanceof ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean) {
            ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean sf = (ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean) bean
            GrailsApplication ga = sf.grailsApplication
            String domainClassType = DomainClassArtefactHandler.TYPE
            for (Class c in domainClasses) {
               ga.addArtefact(domainClassType, c)
            }
         }
      }
      bean
   }

   @Override
   Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      bean
   }
}
```

Another solution would be to try and package the domains classes as a Grails binary plugin, and load the plugin (and therefore its bundled resources) in this post processing method. Hope this helps.

Comment: OMG this truly sucks. Even with this, you **still** need to have a dummy entity class under your application's root package in order to tell GORM "Yes, please do enable persistence for me". I'm raising an issue to the Spring boot folks. Thanks.